# How to get model attributes when using Spring WebFlux router functions?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-webflux, project-reactor

**Spring WebFlux** provides a choice of two programming options: *Annotated Controllers* and *Functional Endpoints*. With the first one, we can use `@ModelAttribute` annotation to transfer model attributes from controller to the view (such as **Thymeleaf** html-template) and vise versa. However, when it comes to router functions, so far I have just figured out how to attach model attributes to `ServerResponse`, but can't find a way to get them back. Consider the following code snippet:

```java
@Configuration
public class StudentsRouterFunctions {

    // inject repository
    private final StudentsCrudRepository repo;

    public StudentsRouterFunctions(StudentsCrudRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @Bean
    RouterFunction<?> routs() {
        return RouterFunctions.route()
                .GET("/students", this::showStudents)
                .POST("/students", this::saveStudent)
                .build();
    }

    // #1: GET-handler
    private Mono<ServerResponse> showStudents(ServerRequest request) {

        // set model attributes
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
        Mono<Student> studentsList = repo.findAll().collectList();
        Mono<Student> newStudent = Mono.just(new Student());
        model.put("students", studentsList);
        model.put("studentForm", newStudent);

        // render the view
        return ServerResponse.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .render("students-template", model);
    }

    // #2: POST-handler
    private Mono<ServerResponse> saveStudent(ServerRequest request) {

        // and here I somehow need to get my new student object 
        // back from the view via "studentForm" model attribute

        // Student newStudent = request.getModel().get("studentForm"); 
        // !!! however, ServerRequest.getModel() method doesn't exist

        return repo.save(newStudent)
                .then(ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT)
                        .render("redirect:/students", new Object()));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ServerRequest::getModel` method but [`ServerRequest::bodyToMono(Class)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/ServerRequest.html#bodyToMono-java.lang.Class-) that extracts the body where is your model to `Mono<T>`.

Then use the advantage of the return type of the reactive repository's method [`ReactiveCrudRepository::save`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/reactive/ReactiveCrudRepository.html#save-S-) returning `Mono<T>` using [`Mono::flatMap`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-).

I have not tested it out, but it should work.

```
private Mono<ServerResponse> saveStudent(ServerRequest request) {
    return request.bodyToMono(Student.class)               // Mono<Student> (a new one)
                  .flatMap(repo::save)                     // Mono<Student> (a saved one)
                  .then(ServerResponse                     // redirect sequence
                      .status(HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT)
                      .render("redirect:/students", new Object()));
}

// .flatMap(repo::save) is the same as .flatMap(newStudent -> repo.save(newStudent))
```

Note the method `Mono::then` discards the element from the source so the redirected object remains as a `new Object()`, so you want to use `Mono::map`.

```
private Mono<ServerResponse> saveStudent(ServerRequest request) {
    return request.bodyToMono(Student.class)               // Mono<Student> (a new one)
                  .flatMap(repo::save)                     // Mono<Student> (a saved one)
                  .map(savedStudent -> ServerResponse      // redirect sequence
                      .status(HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT)
                      .render("redirect:/students", savedStudent));
}
```

Comment: When I used your combination `bodyToMono.flatMap.map`, I got an error: __Incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds equality constraints: ServerResponse lower bounds: Mono<ServerResponse>__, so I used combination `bodyToMono.flatMap.flatMap` instead.

Comment: Also, `bodyToMono()` doesn't work in my case, because "studentForm" object is bound in the view to the Thymeleaf's form `th:object="${studentForm}"` attribute, so that when the form is submitted, I get an error: __Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported for bodyType=Student__. To solve this problem, I have to use `ServerRequest.formData()` method instead `ServerRequest.bodyToMono()` and then manually deserialize MultiValueMap<String,String> into Student object before saving it to the repository.

Comment: Apart from those comments, I believe I can accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: I am happy at least I helped you to find a working solution.